# Using react-native run-android produces install error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npx

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for m
ore details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

I have gotten around this for now by opening two Android Studio's. One is located in the android studio folder for the react-native app, and the other is in the root folder for it. I then start a server using: npx react-native start in the root foldered android studio. Then I can launch the app in the other android window, and manipulate the code in the other android studios app.js. Obviously this is not ideal as I have two windows open for one application. I have tried going through the react native environment setup twice now, and same thing. Any tips!?

Comment: run **adb devices** command and see if there is your device listed or not.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying the react-native cli. If so, start a server on the project root folder with react-native start. Spin up another terminal window and run react-native run-android on the project root folder. Make sure you have an android device connected with adb devices command.

Comment: @J.Doe yes the emulator is listed.

Comment: @nithinpp I tried this, same error. I am using npx instead of a downloaded react CLI as it suggests on the website.